Searching more than 1 "exact phrases" in Google scholar
I am using Google Scholar as one of the databases for a SLR. When using the Advanced search, I am not able to search more than 1 "exact phrases" using the operator AND. Is there a way out?

Google Scholar is not a database.

In the box for "with the exact phrase" just type the phrases you want, in double quotes, with the word and in between. I just tried entering

"drug treatment" and "randomized control"

and it worked fine. You could add other limits. (see image).


Thanks a lot! It turns out that the phrases I was trying to search gave no results because they weren't present together in the title afterall!
